# Changing the count of numbers of the y-axis (Python, matplotlib.pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just have a small problem with pyplot.

I am plotting my data in a way like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(i,3,j)
plt.plot(xy.data)
plt.show()
```

With several subplots. Now my problem is: When I have many subplots, the plots become very small and espacially flat. So the numbers that are on my y-axis become impossible to read, cause they overlap each other.

Is it somehow easily possible to change the count of the numbers to something like 3? So I just have the maximum, zero and the minimum? But not the minimum of my function, I would rather keep the minimum (and max) that is currently there. So I just would like to let every step inbetween the current min, 0 and max away.

Thank You all, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(3))
```

[`MaxNLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) sets the amount of ticks, and with the `plt.gca().yaxis` you make this happen on the y-axis.

Comment: plt.gca().yaxis.setmajor_locator(MaxNLocator(3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-8e8d767bab3e> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.gca().yaxis.setmajor_locator(MaxNLocator(3))

AttributeError: 'YAxis' object has no attribute 'setmajor_locator'

Comment: you miss an underscore between set and major ;)

Comment: oh, my mistake, i forgot '_' after set